# What is the equivalent of "navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state;" but in React Navigation 6?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Basically I'm upgrading React Navigation from version 4 to 6. I have an area where navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state; was used to get the state of the previous route.

I know that they switched out "dangerouslyGetParent" for "getParent" and "navigation.state" out for "route.state".

But what about this case? Thanks!

the block of code in question...

```
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const { navBack } = this.state;
    this.hideToast();
    if (navBack) {
      const parentRoute = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state;
      const backRoute = getBackRouteName(
        parentRoute,
        parentRoute.index - 1
      );

      if (backRoute === null) {
        navigation.navigate(navBack);
      } else {
        const replaceAction = StackActions.replace({
          key: backRoute.key,
          routeName: navBack,
          params: {
            navBack,
          },
        });
        navigation.dispatch(replaceAction);
        navigation.goBack();
      }
    } else {
      navigation.goBack();
    }

    return true;
  };
```

Comment: have you tried updating to v5.x first using https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/upgrading-from-4.x/ and then upgrading to v6.x using https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/

Comment: The question is the same regardless of 5 or 6

Comment: Any solution to solve this ?